# Reading huge partitioned data in Memory using Dask from s3

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have a huge dataset(with flair embeddings) on  aws s3 created with dask partitions and divisions, to be precise 150GB parquet files (in total 16 Mn rows and each row have 2050 columns).I want to read 1Mn rows at a time for model training (with a mini- batch of 32) ,

```
index = ddf.index.compute().values
index_batch = index[0:1000000]
data_batch = ddf.loc[index_batch].compute()
```

However it takes a hell lot of time to read that much data in memory , any advise from anyone to make that process faster would be highly appreciated.

```
np.random.shuffle(index),
```

to shuffle the data after each epoch has also been performed.

#dask #daskdistributed

I tried repartitioning the small partitioned files into bigger chunks and try to read but the performance is still the same

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are wanting to take a random sample from every partition of your data. This will require reading every single partition, so that you can pick values. You might have wanted [`DataFrame.sample`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.sample.html) - but first think about whether you really need data from every partition.

If I misunderstood and you just want a slice, then

```
data_batch = ddf.loc[0:1000000].compute()
```

would do.

You didn't say how your data was stored or exactly what you need to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
index_batch would have random indexes e.g. [0,50,100000] so yes I want to reading every single partition.

My data is stored in  compressed parquet files with pyarrow engine on s3 along with indexes(each row have text embeddings along with other features in form of a dataframe).
I am using this to do model training , so keeping 1Mn rows in memory and then picking a batch of 32 rows to train and update the weights of the model and do it over the entire training data in each epoch.This step of slicing from dask dataframe is a bottleneck as it is taking a lot of time

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to choose some rows from each partition without reading the whole of every partition - it is fundamental to how parquet works. With fastparquet, you can directly supply a boolean row selection to each partition, which is a little complex but might keep your memeory use down and maybe save time.

Answer (score 0):

How many files are you reading? Dask read_parquet can be slow to generate metadata on tens of thousands of remote files. Use aggregate_files to reduce the complexity of the metadata generation.

It could also be a bandwidth issue if your network is slow or a lack of distribution if you have only written one (or few) parquet file(s).

Also to @mdurant’s point use sample instead of loc.